In the Original Transformer, How exactly is layer normalization done?
I am assuming we are talking about the Transformer as written in "Attention is all you need" paper.
Let's say the in the normalization layer is m x n, where m is the context size and n is the embedding dimension.
I have read that   (x-$\mu$)/($\sigma$) is used, but its not clear to me how is this being applied.
Are we calculating the mean and standard deviation for each row and applying it to each row? Or is it across the entire matrix?
